# Convert Base 64 String to BytesIO

Tags: python, json, flask, base64, google-cloud-platform

Thanks to anyone that can help with this, its my first question so hopefully it's not super obvious.

I Have an image that's being passed as a base64 string (using slim image cropper). I want to convert that to a file then send it to Google Storage as a blob.

Previously I've been just sending the file like below

```
image = request.files.get('image')
client = _get_storage_client()
bucket = client.bucket(current_app.config['CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET'])
blob = bucket.blob(filename)

blob.upload_from_string(
    image.read(),
    content_type=content_type)
```

Now I'm dealing with the below code.

```
cropped_image = json.loads(request.form.get('slim[]'))
data = cropped_image['output']['image']
```

data variable is a string:

```
data = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBD...'
```

i'm stuck not sure if I need to encode to base64, decode from base64, turn it to a bytestring then encode/decode??

I've tried just sending it as is using bytesIO and StringIO

```
image = BytesIO(data)
blob.upload_from_string(
    image.read(),
    content_type=content_type)
```

and I get a black picture uploaded, really try to not ask questions without researching first but this one has me stumped.

Thanks.

Comment: The arguments to `upload_from_string` are the same in the second case as the first.  The variable `image`, which you create from `data`, isn't used in the call to `upload_from_string`.  Is that right?

Comment: In the first example I am passing a filestorage uploaded from a web form.

Comment: I've tried sending the data variable to upload_from_string and get the same results as using bytesIO or StringIO.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`re.sub("data:image/jpeg;base64,", '', b64_str).decode("base64")` works in Python2. In Py 2, the `str` is `bytes` actually.

UPDATE

```
from base64 import b64decode

with open("test.jpeg", 'wb') as f:
    f.write(b64decode(re.sub("data:image/jpeg;base64,", '', b64_str)))

# or

image = BytesIO(b64decode(re.sub("data:image/jpeg;base64", '', b64_str)))
```

Comment: How would I do this with the data variable holding the string? like this? `re.sub(data, '', b64_str).decode("base64")`

Comment: @Solutionist replace the `b64_str` with your data variable holding the string.

Comment: I get the following `fixeddata = re.sub("data:image/jpeg;base64", '', data.decode("base64"))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: apologies    `fixeddata = re.sub("data:image/jpeg;base64", '', data).decode("base64")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: Try to transform data to bytes. `re.sub("data:image/jpeg;base64", '', bytes(data)).decode("base64")`.

Comment: `fixeddata = re.sub("data:image/jpeg;base64", '', bytes(data)).decode("base64")
TypeError: string argument without an encoding`

Comment: @Solutionist See my updated answer. The previous answer is used in my flask project to transform base64 encoded image from database with the `MEDIUMBLOB` field. I will debug to check the type of `b64_str` and explain the reason why it works in my project.